# checking the version of chatter using python -m chatterbot --version.This is the error

Tags: python

python -m chatterbot --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/**main**.py", line 20, in 
print(get_chatterbot_version())
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/**main**.py", line 15, in get_chatterbot_version
return config['chatterbot']['version']
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 958, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'chatterbot'

Comment: Is chatterbot correctly installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably this will work for you:

```
git clone https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git 
python3 setup.py install
```

Sources:

https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1940

Hope it help, have a nice day,

David.

Comment: Your welcome! ^^ if it still work, please put the answer as the good one so if someone have the same problem know that this is the way to solve it. (sorry for my english)